# Reset password using Firestore authentication using python API

Tags: firebase-authentication, python-3.7, firebase-admin

Aim is to send a password reset link using Firestore authentication. Initially I used the default action URL and the script was working fine. But when I changed the action URL, I am getting OK in the web page. It is not resetting the password.

Code:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials,firestore,auth
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail, Email
from python_http_client.exceptions import HTTPError

sg = SendGridAPIClient(os.environ["SENDGRID_API_KEY"])
 
action_code_settings = auth.ActionCodeSettings(
    url='https://us-central1-xxxx.cloudfunctions.net/xxxx',
    handle_code_in_app=False
)

link = auth.generate_password_reset_link(Email)

html_content = f"""
    <p>Hello,</p>
    <p>Click on the link to reset the password.</p>
    <p>{link}</p>
    <p>If you didn't ask to reset password, you can ignore this email.</p>
   """

message = Mail(
   to_emails=Email,
   from_email=Email('abc@gmail.com', "ABC System"),
   subject="Reset password for ABC System",
   html_content=html_content
 )

 try:
    response = sg.send(message)
    return f"The password for {Email} has been reset."

 except HTTPError as e:
    print(e.message)
    return e.message
```

Can someone point out what is wrong.